# Problema con retornar un objeto desde un factory en angular JS

Tags: angularjs-2.0

miren este es mi codigo.

```
Traer:function($scope) {        

    $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:'http://localhost:8080/VENTAS2017/serviciosPHP/Categoria/GETCATEGORIA.PHP'
    }).then(function successCallBack(response){ 
        $scope.objeto = [];
        $scope.objeto = response.data;                                                
    },function errorCallBack(response){
        return response.data;
    });     
    return $scope.objeto;    
},
```

Ahora amigo el error es que pasa algo raro cuando envio la peticion la primera vez, retorna indefinido pero ya la segunda vez retorna el objeto.

Comment: cual se supone que es el error amigo?

Comment: Amigo es que mira le doy consultar y el me devuelve un valor indefinido, vuelvo y le doy consultar y me devuelve el objeto, no entiendo por que sucede eso bro, me podrias ayudar por team weiver ?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que no se angular 2, pero deja que seguro aparece alguien, te di un voto positivo, en angular ya he visto muchos problemas aqui sobre eso. otra cosa pones angular 2, y estas usando `$scope`, no sera mas bien angular 1?

Answer (score -1):

Lo que ocurre es que estás haciendo una petición ajax que por defecto es asíncrona. Por tanto la primera vez que ejecutas la función se pide una promesa ajax

```
$http({
    method:'GET',
    url:'http://localhost:8080/VENTAS2017/serviciosPHP/Categoria/GETCATEGORIA.PHP'
})
```

y se ejecuta un return sobre un objeto que todavía no tiene valor:

```
return $scope.objeto;
```

En un tiempo indeterminado entre tu primera petición y la siguiente, se resuelve la promesa dando valor al objeto

```
.then(function successCallBack(response){ 
    $scope.objeto = [];
    $scope.objeto = response.data;                                                
}
```

Por tanto, la siguiente vez que ejecutas al hacer la misma secuencia: 1. Hacer una promesa ajax, 2. Hacer un return. El objeto que devuelves ya tiene valor.

La solución está en ejecutar la función en la que usas el `$scope.objet` dentro de la función `then` o esperar a que $scope.object se actualice si lo usas dentro de tus templates.

```
Traer:function($scope) {        

    $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:'http://localhost:8080/VENTAS2017/serviciosPHP/Categoria/GETCATEGORIA.PHP'
        }).then(function successCallBack(response){ 
            // Aquí ejecuta la función directamente sobre response.data en caso de ser necesario
            $scope.objeto = response.data;
    },function errorCallBack(response){
        // Haz algo con response.data. No lo devuelvas
        response.data;
    });     
    return $scope.objeto;    
},
```